# Php SoapClient: SoapFault Exception: Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I make soap requests using this Code :

```
try {
    $S = new \SoapClient($this->wsdl);
    $method = 'method';
    $params = array('ID' => $Id, 'Code'=> $Code);
    return  $S->__call($method, $params);
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    return  $e->getMessage();
}
```

But an Exception is raised :

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host

I tried to return all functions described in the WSDL for the Web service

```
$S = new \SoapClient($this->wsdl);
return $S->__getFunctions();
```

And I have all functions including my 'method' used above.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems pretty clearly stated in the error message ... the specified endpoint is unreachable... Either it is down or your wsdl is pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: But the __getFunctions() function works very well!

Comment: It's getting the functions defined within the wsdl... it doesn't have to reach out to the endpoint for that